Cleaning bad recording due to broken audio mixer input
Yesterday I recorded an event with a ZOOM recording device.
There were 3 inputs. Two handheld microphones. One headset microphone. All of these were connected to speaker and when listened through speakers all was good.
But after listening the recording I noticed the sound coming from headset microphone is so poor. Even though the output from the mixer to the zoom recorder was the same.
After testing another input for the headset microphone I realized the the previous input was broken Even thought it was good for the speakers.
Now I have an audio device with some clean parts from handheld microphone sound and some bad quality parts from headset microphone. The bad parts has reverb as if the recording is made with a phone microphone from a distance. The audio file is in stereo mode.
I believe this problem is a specific one because the connection between all inputs and the speaker output was ok. The connection between handheld mics and recording output was ok. The only connection that was corrupted was the headset input and recording output. So I am not a sound expert at all but a programmer.
I think the sound was being added some noise in the channel between the input and recording output because this is the only way to this result.
Is there any way do differentiate the real sound and noise in this recording to reduce the reverb and echo? I am adding a link to the part of the audio file for experts to listen and identify the problem. In the the file I am attaching the first part is handheld the second part is headset mic.
I would be very happy is some expert in this sub would identify and guide me to make this sound clean.
If any, please be as precise in your explanation because I have no experience with audio files and cleaning sounds.
https://we.tl/t-dVPT2EjQX5

Hi Abw. Your link doesn't work. I think it expired. But are you basically asking how to remove noise? Because that's probably the most common question on here, with many answers.
